# What should we do with questions that ask about forgiveness and repentance?

Tags: discussion

I am seeing a lot of these questions. Muslims know that allah is the most merciful and in many ayahs and hadtihs Allah states He can easily forgive all sins if someone would repent. Even if someone does something bad again, Allah would still forgive him 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc... Do we have a canonical answer for such questions ? if Not. Should we write one and link new questions to that answers ?

Answer (score 3):

A duplicate target with a canonical answer may be a good option.

Similar to ["Read this before declaring it's not fair"](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3324/), we may need to consider a "duplicate target" for questions that ask about Allah accepting one's deeds or prayers or about Allah forgiving one's sins. Obviously, no one can answer on behalf of Allah.

Granted, some of these questions may be editable into an acceptable form (e.g., by explaining expiation or repentance), in which case one should exercise common sense prior to voting as a duplicate.

Examples:

- Will Allah accept my ...

  - [Did Allah accept my Shahadah given my doubts?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35932/)
  - [I am having mental illness. Will Allah accept my prayers?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47326/)
  - [Will Allah accept my prayers during the fasting days to make up for masturbating?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32889/)
  - [Will my zakat be accepted given that I am not performing prayer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35017/)
- Will Allah forgive my ...

  - [I married a non-Muslim, will Allah forgive?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/42905/)
  - [What if we are praying Salat in the wrong way unintentionally? Will we be forgiven by Allah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47296/)
  - [Will Allah forgive me for backbiting in the past since I didn't know?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13164/)
  - [Will Allah punish me for thinking about sexual relations?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37401/)

Comment: For repentance, it's why I asked this question [Does the process of repentance differ significantly based on the sin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/41427/17163).